# VB6 PDF printing on webserver

Tags: .net, pdf, printing, vb6, webserver

This is a strange one and is a bit tricky to explain.

We have a website that creates PDF files for users. We already have a DLL from another application that allows us to create the PDF files with what we want in them and are trying to utilize this in our website to avoid a lengthy re-write of said DLL code. The catch is the DLL is in VB6. We are having the issue that when the user clicks print the moment our DLL touches the printer then we get an exception (but only if there is no user logged onto the webserver).

We have a similar thing in the .NET code that runs doing a smaller job but essentially it's the same thing, and this appears to work fine.

Has anyone done or seen anything like this and do they have any idea if what we are doing can be done and if so where we would look in an attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: Does your server use Win2008? If for some reason your VB dll uses GDI+ for printing, it will not work from a service running on Win2008.

Comment: Hi, yes we are using Win2008 but our vb6 dll does not use GDI+

Comment: Maybe it uses some other third-party component internally? How is your dll rendering the PDF content to the printer device context? On any case this looks to me as a problem with permissions or not allowed operations on a Win2k8 service.

Comment: Why is a dll on a webserver trying to touch the printer on the webserver?  Is that what you intended to happen?  As a website user, I want to print to my local printer not for a copy to pop out in some data center somewhere.

Comment: It's creating a PDF file on the server to be viewed by the client's browser. Not printing an actual document, the idea is they view the PDF on their machine and then if they wish to print they can print the PDF to their local printer from there.

Comment: Which third party DLL are you using? Amyuni?